# Hotkey not working when showintaskbar set is false

Tags: c#, registerhotkey

I'm using RegisterHotKey to set the global keyboard shortcut, and it works if the main form is visible or minimized. But if the form showintaskbar set is false dont work hotkey.

Any ideas?

[source code](http://pastebin.com/ahyEZqAT)

Comment: Without showing your actual code, it's hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: [source code](http://pastebin.com/ahyEZqAT)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegisterHotKey not working with invisible forms (c#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553607/registerhotkey-not-working-with-invisible-forms-c)

Comment: Please include the source code, rather than link it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to register the hotkey AFTER you set the
ShowInTaskbar state. Converserly, if you later toggle the ShowInTaskbar
state, you need to reregister the hotkey. Something about changing the
ShowInTaskbar state disables the hotkey.

Comment: Yes, that's right
Before set is showintaskbar false, hotkey registered ,But it still does not work